# Why `ln -s scripts/hooks/prepare-commit-msg .git/hooks/` does not work?

Tags: bash, git

Why `ln -s scripts/hooks/prepare-commit-msg .git/hooks/` does not create a proper working link? `scripts/hooks/prepare-commit-msg` exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look at the symlink you created with that `ln` command:

```
$ ls -l .git/hooks/prepare-commit-msg
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 lars lars 32 Mar  3 07:35 .git/hooks/prepare-commit-msg -> scripts/hooks/prepare-commit-msg
```

There is no path `scripts/hooks/prepare-commit-msg` available from inside the `.git/hooks` directory. For that to work, you need to provide an appropriate relative path:

```
$ ln -s ../../scripts/hooks/prepare-commit-msg .git/hooks
```

Comment: A clearer illustration might be to `cd` into `.git/hooks` and then run `ls`, since from the root of the repo, both paths still look valid at a glance.